# How to getObject from S3 protocol url using AWS SDK JS v3?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a URL that looks like: `s3://mybucket/data.txt`. I'm trying to retrieve that item using the AWS SDK JS v3 library (`@aws-sdk/client-s3`).

When using the `getObject` command, it requires a Bucket and Key.

How can I pass in the S3 protocol URL into the S3 client to get the object based on that URL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can parse the URI to get the bucket name and key name out of it:

```
import url from 'url';
var s3uri = new URL('s3://some-bucket-name/path/to/object.dat');
var bucket = s3uri.hostname;
// Ignore the first slash, it's not part of the key name
var key = s3uri.pathname.substr(1);

console.log("Bucket: " + bucket + " / Key: " + key);
// Bucket: some-bucket-name / Key: path/to/object.dat
```